# Correct boot order if you want to boot from USB Flash Drive?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, usb-flash-drive

What is the correct boot order on BIOS Boot menu if I want to boot my laptop from a USB Flash Drive?

Is This Correct (My BIOS Default)?

1. CD/DVD ROM
2. USB
3. USB Floppy
4. Hard Disk
5. Network Device

Answer (score 2):

USB

CD/ DVD ROM

USB Floppy

Hard Disk

Network Device

This is how I would do it